# maven-assembly-plugin and ar archives

Tags: maven-2

In my maven project I want to assemble an ipkg file (This is like a Debian Package but for embedded systems). For this I need to create AR archives with the assembly plugin. In the [plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) I found this: "and any other format that the ArchiveManager has been configured for". But I can't find out how to "configure" the "ArchiveManager". How can I do this? Or better: Maybe someone already did this and I can use an already existing plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're new to maven then it's almost "mission impossible".
**In theory** this should work as follows:

- Implement your own `Archiver`.
- Provide META-INF/plexus/components.xml:

...

```
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.Archiver</role>
      <role-hint>myformat</role-hint>
      <implementation>com.acme.foo.MyArchiverImplementation</implementation>
      <instantiation-strategy>per-lookup</instantiation-strategy>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

- Add your artifact as a build extension.

See [`plexus-archiver`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-archiver) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [maven-pkg-plugin](http://wiki.evolvis.org/mvn-pkg-plugin/index.php/Hauptseite) (mentioned [here](http://blogs.fsfe.org/robertschuster/?p=36) and [here](http://smancke.blogs.evolvis.org/2008/03/05/jalimo-for-openmoko/))?